# Java AWS s3 / simple odd problom with a logic processor

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon Web Services s3, and am using it to,
- open a connection (working fine)
- open an input stream from a text file that has usernames and passwords listed username,password
username,password
...
all that works fine, I run into issues when trying to check if a username matches with a password.

Take a look,

```
            while (INFINITE == 1) {
            System.out.println("ran");
            if (tryToLogin == true) {
                System.out.println("ran2");
                tryToLogin = false;
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(object.getObjectContent()));
             String lineValue = null;
             while((lineValue = br.readLine()) != null && loggedInAs == null){
                 String splitResult[] = lineValue.split(",");
               if ("saucymeatman" ==  splitResult[0] && "mufasa" == splitResult[1]) {
                loggedInAs = splitResult[0];
                System.out.println("logged in");
             //ui.usernameLogin.getText()
               }
               else {
                    System.out.println("SPLIT 0 : " + splitResult[0]);
                    System.out.println("SPLIT 1 : " + splitResult[1]);
               }
             }
             }
        }
```

Even though 
"saucymeatman" ==  splitResult[0] && "mufasa" == splitResult[1]
It does not print "Logged in" or set loggedInAs to anything.
I am sure that splitResult[0] equals "saucymeatman"
because it prints "SPLIT 0 : saucymeatman".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use `==` to compare `String` values; use the `equals` method of the `String` class.

Comment: Works great! Can I give you some kind of reward like a "Thumbs up" or "+1" or whatever this site has for helping?

Comment: If you'd like.  But normally this kind of question gets marked as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `==` to compare String values; use the [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method of the `String` class.  The `==` operator compares objects references to determine if they refer to the same object; it doesn't compare string contents.